# Python - My class raise ValueError, but it is not handled by except

Tags: python, exception, raise

My Sample Code:

```
from tkinter import *

class first:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = Tk()
        ...
    def test(self):
        try:
            self.value = self.dict[key]
        except KeyError:
            try:
                second()
            except ValueError:
                print('Finally')

class second:
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = Toplevel()
        ...
        self.button = ttk.Button(parent=self.frame, text='GO', command=self.go_click)
        ...

    def go_click(self):
        raise ValueError('Not Valid')
```

That´s just an example! The problem is that the ValueError is raised by the second class, but it is not handled by the except clause of the first class. Below the traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
File "........", line xxx, in goclick
    raise ValueError('Not Valid')
ValueError: Not Valid
```

How can I properly handle it?

Thanks,

Comment: because you complete the call to `second()` before you `go_click()`

Comment: you didn't handle `go_click`.

Comment: Your `try` will only catch exceptions that occur during creation of the class instance.  It won't catch all exceptions that any part of the class ever raises.

Comment: Thanks @BrenBarn, I will have to handled it another way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
from tkinter import *

class first:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = Tk()
        ...
    def test(self):
        try:
            self.value = self.dict[key]
        except KeyError:
            try:
                second()
            except ValueError:
                print('Finally')
            print "OK CALLED SECOND()!!!!" #######THIS PRINT MEANS YOUR DONE HERE

class second:
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = Toplevel()
        ...
        self.button = ttk.Button(parent=self.frame, text='GO', command=self.go_click)
        ...

    def go_click(self):
        raise ValueError('Not Valid')
```

in order to actually handle that error you would need to override tkinters event loop ... not very easy(or good practice in general)

a better way to do it would be to handle the error in the `go_click` function its self something like

```
  def go_click(self):
      try:
         self.submit_form()
      except ValueError:
         print "VALIDATION ERROR!!"
```

Comment: So I´ll need to handled it on another way. Thanks.